# Adding PHP string variable to textbox value that includes quotation marks

Tags: php, string, variables, escaping, quotes

I'm trying to populate an HTML text box with a php variable. The variable is a string with a single quotation mark in it and is retrieved from a database.

When I echo the variable it looks as it's supposed to - ie. "here's my string" so, it's correctly displaying the ' single quotation mark.

But when I try to put that variable into a text box field ie.

```
<? echo("<input type='text' name = 'title' value='$title'/>");?>
```

The quotation mark is ignored..

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've tried running the variable through a number of HTML formatting functions but to no avail.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by 'The quotation mark is ignored'?

Comment: Are you saying a string such as `"how'd you go?"` becomes `"howd you go?"` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change it to this:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

[htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) are used to convert strings in to HTML with correct encoding.

The `ENT_QUOTES` option ensures that the apostrophes and speech marks are also correctly encoded.

Comment: +1 For putting the PHP where it belongs, in the `value` attribute only

Comment: Thanks for the response, that was damn quick.. I've sorted it though. The problem was that I had the value=' in single quotes. The single quote in the variable was ending it.. I just used escape charaters in the value= and used double quotes instead ie.. value=\"$title\"

Comment: @Mark: You should still do the above, even though you have it working now.  A small change to the contents of that variable and it could break.  In general any variable you output should be dealt with that way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` with the ENT_QUOTES flag to escape quotes in the text before outputting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo '<input type="text" name="title" value="'.htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES).'" />'; ?>
```

Comment: And if `$title` contains double quotes?